# How to exclude ".gz" files in logrotate

Tags: linux, gzip, logrotate

I am using `logrotate` version 3.12.3. How do I tell `logrotate` to exclude files that are already rotated/compressed?

For example, if I am rotating all files in `/var/log` as

```
"/var/log/*" {
   compress
   missingok
   dateext
   rotate 4
   size=5000k
}
```

after a file is compressed, how do I tell `logrotate` to not rotate already rotated/compressed files? For example:

```
/var/log/file1
```

after logrotation it becomes

```
/var/log/file1.20211212.gz
```

I tried

```
tabooext + .gz
```

on top of definitions but it doesn't seem to take effect.

From `man logrotate`

> **include file_or_directory**
>
> Reads the file given as an argument as if it was included inline where the include directive appears. If a directory is given,
>   most of  the  files  in  that
>   directory  are  read in alphabetic order before processing of the including file continues. The only files which are ignored are
>   files which are not regular
>             files (such as directories and named pipes) and files whose names end with one of the taboo extensions, as specified by the
>   tabooext directive.

If something like below worked, that would have been good.

```
/var/log/*[!".gz"] {
}
```

Thank you.

***EDIT***

Maybe do something like

```
/var/log/*[!.][!g][!z] {
..
}
```

but it skips file named `/var/log/test1gz`. How do I match the `.` character with globbing?

Answer (score 4):

Try to find all glob possibilities that does not accept `*.gz`. As you have three letters (`.`, `g`, `z`), there are `2^3 = 8` possible combinations (3 characters, 2 states `x` and `!x`), minus one which is `*.gz`.

The seven other possibilities are the following:

- All files that don't have an extension point as third last but end with `gz` (e.g. `filegz`)

  ```
  /var/log/*[!.]gz
  ```
- All files which 2-letters extension doesn't begin by `g` but ends by `z` (e.g. `file.7z`)

  ```
  /var/log/*.[!g]z
  ```
- All files which 2-letters extension begins by `g` but doesn't end by `z` (e.g. `file.gg`)

  ```
  /var/log/*.g[!z]
  ```
- All files that don't end with `.gz` but end with a `z` (e.g. `file.ezz`)

  ```
  /var/log/*[!.][!g]z
  ```
- All files that don't end with `.gz` but with `g` as second to last letter (e.g. `file.cgi`)

  ```
  /var/log/*[!.]g[!z]
  ```
- All files which 2-letters extension is not `gz` (e.g. `file.hh`)

  ```
  /var/log/*.[!g][!z]
  ```
- Finally, all files that don't finish by `.gz` (e.g. `file.txt`)

  ```
  /var/log/*[!.][!g][!z]
  ```

So this gives us:

```
/var/log/*[!.]gz
/var/log/*.[!g]z
/var/log/*.g[!z]
/var/log/*[!.][!g]z
/var/log/*[!.]g[!z]
/var/log/*.[!g][!z]
/var/log/*[!.][!g][!z]
{
  ...
```

The combinations can be generated with python:

```py
import itertools as it

suffix = '.gz'
states = ([x, '![%c]' % x] for x in suffix)
for res in it.product(*states):
    print ''.join(res)
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to specify a complete folder. You can define a file aswell. So first you should make sub folders for every service that you have a better overview. There you can place your logs into. You shouldn't put that on your complete log folder because there are some more rotate scripts located.

for example:

```
/var/log/yum.log {
    missingok
    notifempty
    size 30k
    yearly
    create 0600 root root
}
```

Comment: I have few programs that write their logs into /var/log (or say /var/log/custom) dir. on process restart, each of those processes create a new log by appending timestamp to its name. I'd like to define a glob that can exclude files that are already rotated. if there is a way to match dot looks like i could define a glob with *[!.][!g][!z] to tell files not ending with ".gz".